# How to remove `created_at`, `updated_at` from insert query (when create a model record)?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

There is a backend page with a form with two fields (`fake_uid`, `auth_key`). When I create new record an error occurs and tells the following:

`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'fake_uid' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into 'fakes_list' ('fake_uid', 'auth_key', 'updated_at', 'created_at') values (45345, 345345, 2019-02-03 09:57:11, 2019-02-03 09:57:11))...`

The table `fakes_list` doesn't have `updated_at` and `created_at` columns. How can I **remove** them from the query? And how to change `fake_uid` to name of some column? Because there is no such column, indeed (as the error says).

I tried to add $purgable variable to my model:

`use \October\Rain\Database\Traits\Purgeable;`
`protected $purgeable = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];`

Not working. But if I add, for example, `fake_uid` - it will be removed from the query. Hm??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#property-timestamps

By default, a model will expect created_at and updated_at columns to exist on your tables. If you do not wish to have these columns managed automatically, set the $timestamps property on your model to false:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

To remove the fake_uid column, edit the fields.yaml file associated to the backend form that you are using and remove / change the name of that field.

Comment: Omg, I didn't even know that these things called like so. Thank you very much!